# Generating statistics using PHP and Zend Framework

Tags: php, zend-framework, statistics

I want to build a statistics generator that should be able to use intervals such as hour, day, week, month etc and group on different levels such as customer, campaign, project. I first built this as a standard action function in a controller but I feel I might actually want to break this out and make it a class and make it reusable. Are there any good standards for building these type of statistics generators in a general way?

Add data collections, set interval and set grouping and a start and end date feels like the usage I would be needing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out http://www.phpclasses.org/ for built classes but if your using zend framework i thin you mean the word model not class if your using an MVC your building a model

O and for statics use your views and just use google analytics its pointless trying to build one better

Comment: true indeed... But a model IS still a class ;)

Comment: yeas but its an Extended class from ZF and what more is you have to namespace a class in ZF thats why its becomes a model
any ways there are a couple of graph system on that site that would help you they use the GD lib then you just sort of need to give it the data

Answer (score 0):

I do not believe that this should be a Zend Framework question, it's to abstract of a problem and has nothing to do with the MVC framework you're using, just the M part, because the problem you are trying to solve is tied to your data model.

You can take a look at how Doctrine and Propel handle adding criteria to the queries, that could be a good place to start.

Answer (score 0):

Two best solution Using [Google Analytics Class](http://www.zfsnippets.com/snippets/view/id/30/google-analytics-view-helper)

> Google Analytics View Helper

or [Piwik](http://piwik.org/)